# PHP - Is there a way to echo text where the echo is?

Tags: php, echo

So basically what I'm trying to do call a function in my main PHP page from a .php file which is just for processing data. That function basically calls echo. I want to call that function in a way that it really echoes where it sits, not where it is called from. Is there a way to do this?

php in index.php:

```php
<?php
   function writeNot($text) {
       echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
       "addNotification(\"$text\");",
       '</script>';
   }
?>
```

php in process.php:

```
writeNot('The file has been successfully uploaded!');
```

I expect that the function echoes the HTML (which calls some Js) into the index.php, but what I assume is that it echoes into the process.php file, which I don't really want.

Comment: "Where it sits" means where you declare the function?

Comment: Your code should be more readable.

Comment: @Johannes Yes. I exactly tried to mean that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use return **instead** of echo

```
   <?php
   function writeNot($text) {
       return'<script type="text/javascript">',
       "addNotification(\"$text\");",
       '</script>';
   }
?>
```

Then use echo to print out the string that is returned from the function

```
echo writeNote($text);
```

And you should call the function inside index.php to execute it

Comment: While I agree this is a good approach to follow in general, the code you've given has exactly the same results as the original.

Comment: That does exactly what `echo` does because the function is always executed at the point of calling `writeNote()` and not declaring it.

Comment: Yes it’s as i get from the question he want set the function output and reuse it.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question  he should call the function inside the index.php to achieve that 

Comment: @hazemali So if I'm correct, is that the only way I can achieve it? Because then I'm thinking of merging the two files.

Comment: Yes you are right .. php doesn’t execute a function or an object unless you called it.

Answer (score -2):

so that it gives you first to include your file 'index.php' in 'process.php'